# Re-setting date to null invalidates Date Format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery DatePicker in a simple form. I want to be able to clear the date (leaving the input blank). I have achieved this with some extra code, but after clearance I'm losing the date formatting 'yy-mm-dd', it is reverting to 'mm-dd-yy'. I have tried re-applying the formatting as part of the clearance, but it has no effect (see below).
How can I achieve this, please?

```
<li>
    <label class='wide' for="startDate">Start Date</label>
    <input class='datepicker' type='text' id='startDate' name='start_date' size='16'/>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="button" value="Clear dates" class="" id="clear-dates">
</li>



$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        var calDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
        var startDate = dateToSQL (calDate);  // my dateToSQL function is elsewhere
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            defaultDate: startDate
        });
    });
});

var $dates = $('#startDate').datepicker();

$('#clear-dates').on('click', function () {
    $dates.datepicker('setDate', null);
    $dates.datepicker.dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
});
```

I've tried it two ways in the snippet above (not simultaneously), but neither work

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be very simple:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
```

It seems that you can only initialise the date picker directly once, after that you need the 'Option' route.